# Convert Tkinter py file into EXE file

Tags: python, tkinter, exe, cx-freeze

im trying to convert my tkinter file into EXE using cx_freeze, but i got this error all the time
[the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7esMH.png)

translation of the hebrew part: module didnt found

my setup file code is:

```
    import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import os

os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = "C:\\Users\\royreznik\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-32\\tcl\\tcl8.6"
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] =  "C:\\Users\\royreznik\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-32\\tcl\\tk8.6"


build_exe_options = {"includes": ["tkinter"]}

base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"

setup(
    name = "simple_Tkinter",
    version = "0.1",
    description = "Sample cx_Freeze Tkinter script",
    options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
    executables = [Executable("tal1.py", base = base)])
```

and my main file is:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()


Entry1 = Entry(root)
Entry2 = Entry(root)

Entry1.grid(row=0)
Entry2.grid(row=1)

Label1 = Label(root, text="null")
Label1.grid(row=4)

def funca():
    phrase = Entry1.get()
    words = phrase.split()
    wordCount = 0;
    for word in words:
        if word == Entry2.get():
            wordCount = wordCount+1
    Label1.configure(text=wordCount)

btn = Button(root, text="get Num",command=funca)
btn.grid(row=3)



root.mainloop()
```

whats the problem?

Comment: I would suggest you to use `py2exe` library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Python directory's DLLs folder you will find `tk86t.dll` and `tcl86t.dll`. You have to copy them into the build folder with the main.py you want to compile.

Then you have to add these two files to the `include_files` parameter in your `setup.py`.

Now, your `setup.py`should look like something like this :

```
import os
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = 'c:/python36/tcl/tcl8.6'
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = 'c:/python36/tcl/tk8.6'

buildOptions = dict(
    packages = [],
    excludes = [],
    include_files=['c:/python36/DLLs/tcl86t.dll', 'c:/python36/DLLs/tk86t.dll']
)

import sys
base = 'Win32GUI' if sys.platform=='win32' else None

executables = [
    Executable('editor.py', base=base)
]

setup(name='editor',
      version = '1.0',
      description = '',
      options = dict(build_exe = buildOptions),
      executables = executables)
```

Of course you may have to adapt the directories paths to make it work.