# Unidentified error . cx_freeze & tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I converted my py file to .exe using cx_freeze. On launch. It gives me the error

https://www.upload.ee/image/7186947/Erir.PNG

MY setup.py

```
 from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
 import os
 import sys
 import os.path

 PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.__file__))
 os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR,'tcl','tcl8.6')
 os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'tcl', 'tk8.6')

setup(
name = "Removed",
version = "3.5",
description = "Removed",
executables = [Executable(script = "test1.py", base = "Win32GUI")])
```

Comment: You should take a look at this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44845123/convert-tkinter-py-file-into-exe-file/44845504?noredirect=1#comment76671428_44845504

Comment: Tried, It did helped but .. Unfortunatley.

Comment: I can't see where did you add the two DLLs paths in setup options as it is explained in the other post.

Comment: Try using `pyinstaller` its easy.

Comment: pyinstaller. damn, It's not available for 3.5 :(

Answer (score 0):

You have not included the Tk and tcl run-times with your script.

You should use the `include_files` arguement to include them.

You just need to make a few modifications to your script:

```
files = {"include_files": ["<Location to Python>/Python36-32/DLLs/tcl86t.dll", "<Location to Python>/Python36-32/DLLs/tk86t.dll"], "packages": ["tkinter"]}
```

And use:

```
options = {"build_exe": files},
```

And it should work.

So your script should look more like this:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import os
import sys
import os.path

PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.__file__))
os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR,'tcl','tcl8.6')
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'tcl', 'tk8.6')
files = {"include_files": ["<Location to Python>/Python36-32/DLLs/tcl86t.dll", "<Location to Python>/Python36-32/DLLs/tk86t.dll"], "packages": ["tkinter"]}

setup(
name = "Removed",
version = "3.5",
description = "Removed",
options = {"build_exe": files},
executables = [Executable(script = "test1.py", base = "Win32GUI")])
```

I hope this helps.